# wordpress woocommerce (2.6.9) override shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to dynamically get shipping costs at checkout from an external system. I've accessed the api and have the costs in variables and now want to 'overwrite' the costs coming from woocommerce with these new ones.

I'm hooking into the woocommerce_package_rates hook but don't seem to be able to get it to work. In the example below, I've just swapped out the variable for a number (100) for simplicity. Any ideas?

```
function flat_rates_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:5'] ) ) {
        $rates['flat_rate:5']->cost = 100;
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can relate an [article](http://www.mingocommerce.com/change-flat-rate-shipping-price/) with exact same scenario. If you go through that article it will describe you how to change flat rates applying your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
function flat_rates_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    foreach($rates as $key  => $rate){
                 // Put your desired slug here for API service
        if($rate->method_id ==  'flat_rate'){
            //  modify the value here
            $rates[$key]->cost  =   25;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Copied from my answer :)